# IIS server reading oracle parameters differently than my local Machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, parameters, sqldatatypes

I'm having issues trying to move my website (asp.net) to the webserver.  Locally everything works and the insert statements uploads into the database.  When i move to the server the data types seem to be interpreted differently causing Oracle error messages. ORA-01843: not a valid month.  Its reading a flat text file.  If i manipulate the raw data on the text file it seems to resolve the issue hence my thought that the data types are not being interpreted correctly on the webserver.

Local Machine: Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010,
Webserver: Windows Server 2008 R2, IIS 7.5.7600.16385

```
try
            {
                StringBuilder fields = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
                StringBuilder realvalue = new StringBuilder();
                OracleCommand dbCommand = new OracleConnection(ConnectionManager.GetiVosConnectionString()).CreateCommand();
                //string showtext = null;

                foreach (TextField tf in TextFields)
                {
                    fields.Append(tf.Name).Append(",");
                    values.Append(":").Append(tf.Name).Append(",");                        
                    dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(tf.Name, tf.Value));
                    //realvalue.Append(tf.Value).Append(",");
                }
                fields.Append("BATCH_ID");
                values.Append(":BATCH_ID");
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("BATCH_ID", batchId));
                dbCommand.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", tfp.TableName, fields.ToString(), values.ToString());  
                //rowinsert = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", tfp.TableName, fields.ToString(), realvalue.ToString());

                try
                {
                    dbCommand.Connection.Open();                        
                    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                finally
                {
                    dbCommand.Connection.Close();
                }
                success++;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                error = true;
                errorMsg = err.Message;
            }
```

Any ideas would help.  Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: If you compare the `CommandText` from your local machine and from the server you'll probably find that the dates on your local machine format differently than the dates on the server due to Windows settings. I'd recommend formatting dates explicitly for Oracle. The safest way to do that is `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`. In other words, today's date (9 August 2013) in "safe" Oracle format would be `DATE '2013-08-09'`.

Comment: Better yet, properly use command parameters to pass datetime values instead of text

Comment: I agree.. If you know the format of the datetime in the textfile, Parse it into a date using C# rather than hoping the server's timezone/regional settings/date format in oracle are the same as the text file, banging a load of text that looks like a date into oracle as text, and hoping it can work out what to convert it to in order to store it in the date column